# VsCode shortcut key for toggling expand behavior of currently opened tab

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

In a split-screen view, when I double-click on a currently opened tab it occupies around 80-90% of available space and when I again click on it it resizes to it's original size.

I'm looking for a shortcut key or a way to configure a shortcut key for this behavior.

Thank you.

I tried searching for "tab" | "file" and similar keywords inside the command palette to find the command we can use to get the expanding and shrinking behavior so that I can assign a shortcut key to it but couldn't find any such commands inside the command palette.

Here's an example:

https://im3.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-3-12a8570a62.gif

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default keyboard shortcut key for toggling the expand behavior of the currently opened tab in VS Code is Ctrl + \ (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + \ (Mac).

If this shortcut key is not working for you, you can try checking if the key binding is already assigned to another command. To do this, open the Keyboard Shortcuts editor by going to File -> Preferences -> Keyboard Shortcuts or by using the shortcut key Ctrl + K Ctrl + S (Windows/Linux) or Cmd + K Cmd + S (Mac).

The feature that toggles the expand behavior of the currently opened tab in VSCode is called "Toggle Editor Group Sizes".

Comment: Thank you, Ben, I can see that `CMD + \\` is assigned to the splitting editor in my case, What's this feature called so that I can remove the existing shortcut key and assign it to this feature?

Thank you

Comment: toggle Editor Group Sizes

Comment: Open the Command Palette by pressing Ctrl+Shift+P on Windows or Cmd+Shift+P on macOS.
Search for "Keyboard Shortcuts" and select it.
In the search bar at the top of the window, type "toggle editor group sizes" to find the command.
Click on the pencil icon next to the command to edit the shortcut key.
Press the keyboard shortcut you want to use for this command (e.g. Cmd+\).
You should see a message that the keybinding is already assigned to another command. Click "Remove" to unassign the shortcut from the other command.

Comment: Thanks mate it worked, Thank you so much. Please update your answer with the feature name and I will mark it as answered.